# Para que serve cache = false em ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

O que exatamente faz o código Ajax quando escrevo:

```
 cache: false,
```

em uma requisição ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando utilizamos a requisição muitas vezes, e ela tem o mesmo retorno o navegador salva o cache assim impossibilitando termos uma resposta atualizada e acabamos vendo o mesmo resultado, colocando `cache: false` evita do navegador salvar o cache sempre mantendo atualiza, outra dica e sempre que estiver desenvolvendo você atualizar a pagina com `Ctrl + F5`.

Answer (score 4):

O `cache:false` no `jQuery Ajax`, serve para forçar as páginas solicitadas a não serem armazenada em cache. (É como se você desabilitasse o cache para aquela página que você enviou a requisição).

Você pode usar tanto em `request` do tipo **[GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)**, quanto **[HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)**